# How to contact a Jobs employer to ask a question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have some questions concerning a Job posting, but I can't seem to find a way to contact the employer (or recruiter?) to have those answered. The only option I see is [Apply Now], I don't want to apply just yet, I would like some info first. Is this possible? Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/228804/principal-cloud-architect-observian).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's appropriate for [tag:jobs] related question (as in, questions about the tag [tag:jobs] on meta) but it might be worthwhile adding a link to the posting, or the link to A posting which replicates behaviour

Comment: Is there a more appropriate place for questions like this? Updated the Q.

Answer (score 22):

Allowing candidates to contact the company before applying is something *optional* that the company must enable when publishing a job listing. So, not every job listing has this option.

But if they enabled it, there is an option, "Ask a question", in the "..." menu:

[image: "..." menu → "Ask a question"]

This option will open a modal dialog that will allow you to write a question to the company before applying.

[image: "Ask a Question" modal dialog]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the "Ask a question" option on said job posting. So I'm assuming this is "optional" for the employer posting. Just randomly checked a bunch other posts, its not there for me. Maybe I'm flagged for something.

Comment: You're right, it's optional for employers to enable "ask a question". So, some jobs have it, others don't. It's certainly not specific to your user account.

Comment: @Max: Seems kind of strange to make this optional. Why would an employer _not_ want to invite clarifying questions? Regardless, this question shows that [there should at least be a \[possibly greyed-out\] option in the UI](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/112250/18837) with an explanation that the employer is not accepting questions. Then the prospective candidate won't waste an hour trying to find [an expected option that does not exist](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/12756/18837)! [Your own boss recommends this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/12761/18837). ;)