# Is there a way to suggest an edit on a job request page?

Tags: support, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, typographical-error

I recently came across a job page, and it has a mildly amusing typo. I'm wondering if there is a way to suggest an edit to fix the typo to the company offering the job.

Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/241898/senior-javascript-developer-software-technology-group?so=i&pg=1&offset=24

This is the typo for those who aren't going to click the link:

Required Skills & Experience
Minim

- um 7+ years professional experience post degree

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to contact an employer is if they're accepting contact as outlined in this question and answer: [How to contact a Jobs employer to ask a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380456/7795130)

Comment: I'm laughing pretty hard at this typo given their second bullet point: "understanding of web markup"

Comment: 1. Ask a question isn't there for some reason :/ 2. Yeah this is pretty funny

Comment: There's more than just one typo there. Pretty much all the bullets for "Required Skills & Experience" are wrong. That page needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: Maybe it is on purpose - they seem to lack someone with _web markup, including HTML5 and CSS3_

Comment: The ones who fixed it are hired

Comment: I believe its better we do not have the power to edit typos in job positions. The way a company advertises their positions often says a lot about the company. I think the fact that they have not fixed them (nor reread the position twice) is useful information to an applicant I think. Same as typos on CVs.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm usually of that same opinion, but [Max's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380582/7795130) indicates that it might be a glitch in the API and not fault of the company, so I'm glad this one was pointed out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Funny indeed, but almost certainly not the fault of the hiring company (Software Technology Group).

Many of our job listings aren't created manually, but through our [API](https://talent.stackoverflow.com/api) and/or through custom integrations with our customers or [syndication partners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378194/what-would-be-the-point-of-sending-users-over-to-linkedin/378779#378779). This looks like a glitch in one of these custom integrations and we're investigating it now.